# Coq: Error: The reference _ was not found in the current environment

Tags: coq

I'm new to Coq.
I'm having trouble defining lists, maps, and trees using units, products, and sums.
I get the error message in the title.
The code above the comment works fine, the code below it does not.

```
Inductive one : Type := nil : one.

Inductive sum (t0 t1 : Type) : Type :=
  | inject_left : t0 -> sum t0 t1
  | inject_right : t1 -> sum t0 t1.

Inductive product (t0 t1 : Type) : Type := pair : t0 -> t1 -> product t0 t1.

Definition list (t0 : Type) : Type := sum one (product t0 (list t0)).

Definition map (t0 t1 : Type) : Type := list (product t0 t1).

(* From here on nothing works. *)

Definition List (t0 : Type) : Type := sum one (product t0 (List t0)).

Definition map (t0 t1 : Type) : Type :=
  sum one (product (product t0 t1) (map t0 t1)).

Definition Map (t0 t1 : Type) : Type :=
  sum one (product (product t0 t1) (Map t0 t1)).

Definition tree (t0 : Type) : Type :=
  sum one (product t0 (product (tree t0) (tree t0))).

Definition Tree (t0 : Type) : Type :=
  sum one (product t0 (product (Tree t0) (Tree t0))).
```

Comment: Looking back, I'm guessing the definition of list worked only because it's already implicitly imported. I guess I need to use _Inductive_ to define recursive types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Definition List (t0 : Type) : Type := sum one (product t0 (List t0)).
```

In Coq, you cannot write a recursive function by using `Definition`, you need to use `Fixpoint` (or something stronger). See http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual003.html#@command14

Now, that's not all, but a recursive definition has to be provably-terminating (to ensure consistency of the logic you use). In particular, you cannot write something like:

```
Fixpoint List (t0 : Type) : Type := sum one (product t0 (List t0)).
```

Since you're doing a recursive call on the same argument you got in. This obviously fails to terminate.

---

Anyway, to define types like these, you should probably rather use `Inductive` (and `CoInductive`), as you already figured out.